# deploy time configuration of web application

Tags: web-applications, spring-mvc

I have a spring web application which has several modules. Each module has its own spring context file. When i assemble the application these context files are built into jar files. Sometimes i need to change some configuration details in these files, for example data source database url. I don't like when all configurations happen at compile time and require rebuilding. Is there a common way of configuring application at deploy time?

Thank you.

Comment: +1 very good question, i have the same issue for my webapp and i would like to know as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending of the application server you use, but a common way to configure database url is to use a property file on the server. The file is loaded when the server starts.

You can load this file using Spring with a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.
Then it's possible to reference a property by its key.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName"><value>${driver}</value></property>
   <property name="url"><value>jdbc:${dbname}</value></property>
 </bean>
```

What application server do you use?

Comment: I use glassfish (solution with jndi is not the case). Where do you put *.properties file and how refer to it?

Comment: Sorry i never used glassfish.

Comment: Ok, where do you put property file in your application and how do you refer to it in spring configuration? I guess it's not very important what type of server is in use.

Comment: <context:property-placeholder    location="file:///${ext.prop.dir}db.properties"/>